# Postgresql order by sum of counts after joins

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have Posts, Comments, and Likes in my webapp.  I would like to order posts by a 'score' which is simply the sum of likes and comments.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
SELECT posts.id, COUNT(comments.id) AS c, COUNT(likes.id) AS l 
FROM posts 
LEFT JOIN comments ON posts.id = comments.post_id 
LEFT JOIN likes ON posts.id = likes.post_id 
GROUP BY posts.id 
ORDER BY SUM(c,l) desc;
```

but I get an error about column c not existing;

Or this:

```
SELECT posts.id, sum(count(comments.id), count(likes.id)) AS score 
FROM posts
LEFT JOIN comments ON posts.id = comments.post_id 
LEFT JOIN likes ON posts.id = likes.post_id 
GROUP BY posts.id 
ORDER BY score desc;
```

but I get an error about name and argument types.

Is there a different way to write this query such that it works?  Thanks!

Comment: Sow the **exact** errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were on roughly the right track, but for some reason you tried to use the `sum` aggregate intead of simple addition:

```
SELECT posts.id, count(comments.id) + count(likes.id) AS score 
FROM posts
LEFT JOIN comments ON posts.id = comments.post_id 
LEFT JOIN likes ON posts.id = likes.post_id 
GROUP BY posts.id 
ORDER BY 2 desc;
```

I used the ordinal-position sort order here, i.e. order by 2nd column.

Comment: Oh man I'm doing a 'DUH' on this one!  It's been a while since I've done more than ActiveRecord =P.  Thank you so much!